# Wine autocreate desktop entries

Tags: wine

I've moved the wine applications I had on an older Ubuntu installation to a newer one, but just the **.wine** folders.

Now I realise that I should have taken the `.local/share/applications` with me, since there is where desktop entries are saved.

Is there any way to **recreate**, as automatically as possible, all **desktop / launchpad entries** for the installed `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works very nicely on my system:

```
find $HOME/.wine -name '*.lnk' -type f -exec bash -c 'wine winemenubuilder "$0"' {} \;
```

It does the following:

1. scans your Wine drive for windows .lnk files
2. creates a Linux .desktop file for each .lnk file
3. creates a folder `$HOME/.local/share/applications/wine`
4. places all of the newly created `.desktop` files in there

Pretty cool?

References:

- [Winemenubuilder](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winemenubuilder)